# Check if binary tree is complete - haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I have a binary tree:

```
data Btree a = Leaf a | Unary (Btree a) a | Binary (Btree a) a (Btree a) deriving Show
```

and some examples to work with:

```
ex1 = Binary (Binary (Leaf 0) 1 (Leaf 2)) 3 (Unary (Leaf 4) 5)
ex2 = Binary (Unary (Leaf 1) 2) 3 (Binary (Leaf 4) 5 (Leaf 10))
ex3 = Binary (Binary (Leaf (0,"a"))(1,"z")(Leaf (2,"x")))(3,"y")(Binary (Leaf (4,"b"))(5,"c")(Leaf (6,"d")))
```

I need to find out whether the tree is complete or not, a tree is complete if the distance between the root and any leaf is always the same up to 1, all of the deepest leaves are located to the left of the others, and there is at most one internal node with unary node that should be located on the second-to-last level.

This is what i have so far

```
complete :: Btree a -> Bool
complete x = fst $ go x where
  go (Leaf _) = (True, 0)
  go (Unary left _) = (leftTrue, 1 + leftCount) where 
    (leftTrue, leftCount) = go left
  go (Binary left _ right) = (leftTrue && rightTrue &&
                            leftCount == rightCount,
                            1 + leftCount + rightCount) where
    (leftTrue, leftCount) = go left
    (rightTrue, rightCount) = go right
```

ex1 & ex3 should return true, but only ex3 is. I believe the Unary part is the issue.

Comment: By definition, a `Unary` node is an incomplete tree, which means you can return early if you ever see one. No need to recurse at that point.

Comment: @chepner how would i implement that? doing  go (Unary left _) = (True, 0) or (False, 0) doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing a complete binary tree with a full binary tree.

Comment: (If you were looking for a *full* binary tree, then `go (Unary _ _) = (False, 0)` would work, where 0 could be any value that type checks, because you'll ultimately ignore the value.)

Comment: I've tried it. All three examples give True. The problem is with the fact that you are counting nodes. You are interested in depths.

Comment: @DavidLukas I don't understand, could you illustrate?

Comment: @Joe What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Please do **no** vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer counts on a code change in the `Unary` part like that: `(leftTrue, 1 + leftCount)` -> `(False, 1 + leftCount)`.

The body of your solution is the `go` function.
The function returns for a subtree
if the left and right subtrees are completely balanced and how many nodes the subtree has.
All depths are the same, like in the ex3.
But if you don't have 2^n-1 nodes and 2^(n-1) leaves, it is impossible to build that tree.
In the description of your problem is allowed little disbalance allowing represent any count of nodes.
Ex1 fulfills the rules ex2 doesn't.
Ex3 is also complete according to your definition.

Under the code, I made ASCII art to the examples.

My solution doesn't count amount nodes of subtrees. It calculates maximal and minimal depths because it allows me to reveal illegal disbalance in any level of a tree.
The boolean value says if the subtree accomplishes your conditions of the complete tree.
It checks that:

1. differences are the same up to one
2. the left subtree has a greater or the same minimal depth as the maximal depth of the right tree.

Checks above also contain the condition about one unary node on the second-to-last level.

Can you guess what belongs to the place ...?

```
data Btree a = Leaf a | Unary (Btree a) a | Binary (Btree a) a (Btree a) deriving Show

ex1 = Binary (Binary (Leaf 0) 1 (Leaf 2)) 3 (Unary (Leaf 4) 5)
ex2 = Binary (Unary (Leaf 1) 2) 3 (Binary (Leaf 4) 5 (Leaf 10))
ex3 = Binary (Binary (Leaf (0,"a"))(1,"z")(Leaf (2,"x")))(3,"y")(Binary (Leaf (4,"b"))(5,"c")(Leaf (6,"d")))

complete :: Btree a -> Bool
complete x = fst $ go x

go :: Btree a -> (Bool,(Int,Int))
go (Leaf _) = (True, (0, 0))
go (Unary left _) = (leftMaxDepth == 0, (1 + leftMaxDepth, 0)) where 
  (leftIs, (leftMaxDepth, leftMinDepth)) = go left
go (Binary left _ right) =
  ( leftIs && rightIs
    ...
    , (1+newMaxDepth
    , 1+newMinDepth )) where
      newMaxDepth = max leftMaxDepth rightMaxDepth
      newMinDepth = min leftMinDepth rightMinDepth
      (leftIs, (leftMaxDepth, leftMinDepth)) = go left
      (rightIs, (rightMaxDepth, rightMinDepth)) = go right
```

> `&& leftMinDepth >= rightMaxDepth && newMaxDepth - newMinDepth <= 1`

ex1: True

```
      3
     / \
    /   \
   1     5
  / \   /
 0   2 4
```

Depths: [3,3,3,2]

ex2: False

```
      3
     / \
    /   \
   2     5
  /     / \
 1     4   10
```

Depths: [3,2,3,3]

ex3: True

```
             (3,"y")
             /     \
           /         \
    (1,"z")          (5,"c")
    /    \            /    \ 
(0,"a")  (2,"x")  (4,"b")  (6,"d")
```

Depths: [3,3,3,3]

Answer (score 0):

> This answer counts on a code change in the `Unary` part like that: `(leftTrue, 1 + leftCount)` -> `(False, 1 + leftCount)`.

[https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Esheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html)

Full binary rtee:
[image]

Complete binary tree:
[image]

Your solution counts on a full binary tree.
Your exercise is about checking if the binary tree is complete.
The algorithm is fine, but the check `leftCount == rightCount` should be changed.
A full binary tree has a minimum depth equal to the maximum depth,
and the left subtree has the same number of nodes as the right.

In a complete binary tree, the situation is more difficult:
Let the number of nodes complete binary tree is x then
x = 2^m-1+n, where m is the minimum depth of the tree and 0 <= n < 2^(m+1) .
Let '1' be the suffix of the left subtree and the suffix '2' of the right.
for subtrees of a complete binary tree, it always holds:

1. If the minimum depths of the left and right subtrees are the same, then the right tree must be full.
2. If the minimum depth of the left subtree is equal to the minimum depth of the right subtree plus one, then the left subtree must be full.

```
getMinDepthAndRest :: Int -> (Int,Int)
getMinDepthAndRest x = getMinDepthandRest' x 0


getMinDepthAndRest' :: Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)
getMinDepthAndRest' x m'
  | x < 2^m'-1 = (m'-1,x-2^(m'-1)+1)
  | otherwise   = getMinDepthandRest' x (m'+1)
                
complete :: Btree a -> Bool
complete x = fst $ go x where
  go (Leaf _) = (True, 1)
  go (Unary left _) = (leftCount == 1, 1 + leftCount) where 
    (leftTrue, leftCount) = go left
  go (Binary left _ right) = (leftTrue && rightTrue &&
                            (m1==m2 && n2==0) || (m1==m2+1 && n1==0),
                            1 + leftCount + rightCount) where
    (m1,n1) = getMinDepthAndRest leftCount
    (m2,n2) = getMinDepthAndRest rightCount
    (leftTrue, leftCount) = go left
    (rightTrue, rightCount) = go right
```